# Pandas add a column whose value can be multiple different values

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'm trying to add a new column to a pandas data set that take the numeric month from one column and stores the corresponding season into the new column.

So in essence,

```
if month == 12, season = 'Winter'
elif month == 2, season = 'Spring'
elif month == 5, season = 'Summer'
else month == 8, season = 'Fall'
```

I haven't seen a really clear solution for this. I've seen how to do it with 2 conditional values, but I'm still fairly new to pandas and python.

Edit: I was able to get it working with one of the solutions listed below (Thanks!), but I should have mentioned that I also need to include months 1,3,4,6,7,9,10,11

Comment: I am assuming you have a big df with many month entries. If you make a df with month-season (aka `df.shape=(2,12)`) then you can do a join on the month column.

Comment: What have you done to try to solve this? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Also, which solution did you manage to get working? I believe mine is now the simplest amongst them.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. Fair warning, since no samples of Input and expected output are given so didn't test it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
conditions=[df['month']==12,
            df['month']==2,
            df['month']==5,
            df['month']==8]
choices=['Winter','spring','Summer','fall']

df['season']=np.select(conditions,choices,default=np.nan)
```

Comment: That did work, yes. Just had to add duplicates of each choice to correspond to the months I didn't explicitly list.

Comment: Heads up, there’s a mismatched quote in there.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, thanks buddy for letting know, I fixed it now, Thanks a TON.

Comment: @Michael, Glad that it helped you. Give it sometime and when you have few answers to your question you could select "anyone" of them as correct one too, cheers.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, Hi Alex, apologies if you are not the down voter, in case you have given down vote then please do lemme know the reason for same, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Oh yeah sorry, I forgot to comment. I thought there was a superior alternative to part of your solution, unfortunately I cannot find what I was thinking of. Your answer is actually better than most here, in the end.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, sure, request you to please revoke down vote, if it looks good to you, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 You have to edit your answer I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dictionary with corresponding numbers and season names, that you can then map onto your new series:

```
season_dict = {12: "Winter",
              2: "Spring",
              5: "Summer",
              8: "Fall"}

df["season"] = df.month.replace(season_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some wild solutions in here.

This obviously isn’t a complete example, but it should be sufficient to understand what you need to do:

```py
# map of month number -> season name
months_dict = {12: 'Winter', 2: 'Spring', ...}

df['season'] = df['month_number'].map(months_dict)
```

Yes, that’s it.

Let me know if you have any questions :)

Answer (score -1):

Since you're already using numpy through pandas, the best way to do this would be through the np.where command.

```py
df['season'] = np.where(df['month']==11|df['month']==12|df['month']==1, 'Winter')
df['season'] = np.where(df['month']==2|df['month']==3|df['month']==4, 'Spring')
df['season'] = np.where(df['month']==5|df['month']==6|df['month']==7, 'Summer')
df['season'] = np.where(df['month']==8|df['month']==9|df['month']==10, 'Fall')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Isn’t `numpy.where()` completely unnecessary here?

Comment: I mean, it's an approach... yours is definitely a bit simpler though :) Wasn't familiar with the .map commands from my limited experience.

Comment: The general approach is fine, what I meant is that `where()` is designed to choose between two alternatives. That first line, for example, could be written `df.loc[df['month'] == 1 | df['month'] == 11 | df['month'] == 12, 'season'] = 'Winter'`, or even simpler `df.loc[df['month'].isin({1, 11, 12}), 'season'] = 'Winter'`.

Answer (score -1):

```
season_map = {12: "Winter",
              2: "Spring",
              5: "Summer",
              8: "Fall"} # Add the rest to this dictionary

df['season'] = df['month_num'].apply(lambda x: season_map[x]) 
# 'season' is the new column, replace 'month_num' accordingly
```

Comment: `df['season'] = df['month_num'].apply(lambda x: season_map[x])` ---> `df['season'] = df['month_num'].map(season_map)`

Comment: I fail to understand why my answer has been downvoted. An accompanying explanation as to where my code is wrong would be welcome and helpful.

Comment: See my comment above.